# Writing multiple page pdf from html template using weasy print and django

Tags: django, weasyprint

Hi am generating PDF's from html template containing a table which number of rows vary, problem is when the rows are in excess of certain number(12) the rest of the rows plus the footer are pushed further below and don't appear in the generated pdf.How can I make it dynamic so that extra info is pushed to new page each having atleast a certain number of rows, or is there a way weasy print to move data to another page if the current is full

So far I have page breaks on the template but it has worked.

```
{% for record in data %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ record.id}}</td>
        <td> {{ record.date}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:12 %}
        <div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
        div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any table at all in your PDF?  I've copied your markup and style and I can't, I can in HTML...

Comment: yes I can see the table,@AdamBarnes

Comment: Could you do me a favour and check out my [repo](https://github.com/Asday/weasyprint-pagination/tree/280b8c584f2ed04128b64edf09a6846e20aa5fa4) - now updated with your code, and let me know if you see the table in the PDF?  I can only see it in the HTML and I'm wondering what's going on...

Comment: @AdamBarnes I cannot view the table too , not sure where the problem might be

Comment: Well then - your question has given me a question.  :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removed the body tags from my template and it worked without using page breaks, weasyprint limits everything in the body tag to be one document in a page.
[another answer that helped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342484/6473175)

Comment: This comment is gold.

Answer (score 1):

I've thrown together a repo to try and reproduce your issue [here](https://github.com/Asday/weasyprint-pagination/tree/23c5027759c61174e574f5ac59b2ea9d7f271f3b), and was unable to.

There's a small syntax error in your question - you're missing the `<` off your second `<div />`, but apart from that, it all looks good.

Comment: thanks it seems smooth ,Could it be my styles are causing the issue.

Comment: That's certainly possible, post your CSS in the answer and I'll update my answer if/when I find the issue.

Comment: I have added the template plus css on the question.